# Sum of ruby arrays in a loop

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to find sum of arrays from 1 to 100.Each number is converted to array containing its own digits eg 97 will be [9,7].Here is what i have tried

```
 (1..100).to_a.each do |i|
      i.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
 end
```

But the sum of arrays are not displayed correctly!
For example;We first create an array of the digits and then return sum

```
[1]=1
[5]=5
[1, 0]=1
[1, 1]=2
[1, 2]=3
[1, 3]=4
[1, 4]=5
```

So sum of individual arrays is to be returned.

Comment: So your task is to find the sum of all the digits in all the numbers between 1 and 100?

Comment: Yes,but its array of the digits.100 is [1,0,0] , 55 is [5,5] etc

Comment: What do you mean by "not displayed correctly"? Its the most significant information in your question.

Comment: Okay number 11 to 13:
[1, 1]=2
[1, 2]=3
[1, 3]=4

Comment: Okay then you just need to change `each` for `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` will iterate the array, but not create a new array with the result of the block. If you want the results at the end, you need to use `map`:

```
result = (1..100).to_a.map do |i|
  i.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
end

result
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

For summing an array you can also simply write

```
array.inject(:+)
# instead of
array.inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
```

Also, the `to_a` is not necessary, you can directly call `each` and/or `map` on a range. So the simplified code would be

```
result = (1..100).map do |i|
  i.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end

result
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
```

Comment: It seems i was confusing between each and map.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

For your codes, you just need to change `each` method to `map`.

```
 (1..100).to_a.map do |i|
      i.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
 end
```

more simplicity way：

```
result = (1..100).to_a.map{ |e| e.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) }

=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1]
```

if you want to get the sum of result, just do like this:

```
result.reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want the **sum** of these new arrays, right? This should solve your problem:

`(1..100).map { |i| i.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).inject(:+) }.inject(:+)`

Answer (score 0):

`digits` and `sum` are newer methods, simplifying this to

```
(1..100).sum{|i| i.digits.sum}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for modern newer versions of Ruby:

```
(1..100).flat_map(&:digits).sum
```